# how to block specific domains in hosts file?

Tags: hosts

I know hot to block single tumblr blog with

```
127.0.1.1 something.tumblr.com
```

but I want to block entire tumblr. I tried `127.0.1.1 tumblr.com` but it's not working.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr) and above, which already have NetworkManager and use dnsmasq by default you don't need to install it.

Just create a file `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/local`:

```
address=/tumblr.com/127.0.0.1
```

and reboot or restart NetworkManager

```
$ sudo service network-manager restart
```

This will block `tumblr.com` and all of its subdomains by redirecting it to localhost (127.0.0.1).

Note this won't do anything unless you also set up your connection to use localhost/[dnsmasq](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Dnsmasq) for name resolution.

---

On older than Trusty versions install `dnsmasq`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install dnsmasq
```

Then in `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` (which you may have to create) add the line:

```
address=/tumblr.com/127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Smart and simple way.

Comment: Note this won't do anything unless you also set up your connection to use localhost/dnsmasq for name resolution.

Comment: and how do you setup connection to use dnsmasq? do you have any link?

Comment: @user1079002 Connection setup can be found in this link https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Dnsmasq

Comment: @RAM can you elaborate a little bit? That link says to install dnsmasq and then edit a certain file. What sort of edits should I do in that file? It's almost 700 lines long and it's not obvious to me if any particular line means "Turn dnsmasq on"

Comment: @Tyler answer has been edited to answer your query about editing the file, it will be visible to you all once the community approves the edited answer

Answer (score 5):

The `/etc/hosts` file does NOT support wildcard subdomains. i.e. you can't say `127.0.0.1 *.tumblr.com` and have it block all URLs of the form *something.tumblr.com*.

If you want to block these at the browser level, you can either use a plugin or better, a filtering proxy like Privoxy.

If you want to block these at the network level, so that no one on that computer can access the sites, you need a simple firewall rule to block *something.tumblr.com*'s IP range, which at first glance appears to be `50.97.143.0/24`, i.e. 50.97.143.0-50.97.143.255.

Answer (score -3):

Looking at and taking the IP address you entered as literal, you are typing it wrong. Instead of 127.0.1.1 it should be 127.0.0.1

Comment: All addresses inside 127.x.x.x are loopback addresses.