# Advanced rules for hosts file

Tags: dns, hosts

I need to add a rule for all subdomains of a domain. I imagine it should looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1 *.example.com
```

As you can see, I need to redirect all requests to any subdomain on example.com to localhost. Well, I know that it is impossible to do it with hosts file. What else can I use in this case?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/118378/in-my-etc-hosts-file-on-linux-osx-how-do-i-do-a-wildcard-subdomain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you say, you can't put wildcards in `/etc/hosts`. It just doesn't work.

That really leaves you with one option: mangle the actual DNS manually. There are several ways you could do this but two spring to mind as the best options...

You *could* run a fully-flegded DNS server locally. This can be a good idea if your internet connection is slow and you'd like all devices on the network to proxy through this server, or you run many domains that you want to override, or some other reason you want to step into the first ring of hell... It won't take a week, but it does requires learning stuff.

Or you could just [override `dnsmasq`'s settings](https://askubuntu.com/a/150180/449). Ubuntu through `network-manager` is already running a sort of DNS proxy in the form of `dnsmasq` and you can tell it to override various domains, quite easily. Here's how I'd route `*.thepcspy.com` (my domain) to `127.0.0.1`:

```
echo address=/thepcspy.com/127.0.0.1/ | sudo tee -a /etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/local
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Then to test:

```
$ nslookup thepcspy.com
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

Name:   thepcspy.com
Address: 127.0.0.1
```

And a subdomain:

```
$ nslookup testing.thepcspy.com
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   testing.thepcspy.com
Address: 109.74.193.118
```

To revert these changes, just edit (or delete) `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/local` and restart `network-manager` again.